# What git commit am I on

Tags: git

To track down a commit that introduced a bug somewhere, I checked out an old commit using

```
git checkout <sha1 hash> .
```

Now is there a way to know what commit you are on? There should be a git command to tell me that I am not on the most recent commit.

I tried

```
git log
git log -1 
git status
git show
```

but all of these show me the most recent commit. (`git status` shows all files after this old commit as modified files, but still it doesnt tell me that I checked out an old commit)

Comment: FYI, if you're trying to track down a commit where you introduced a bug, you should use git bisect, it semi-automates the whole process by performing a binary search on your git history based commit hashes.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about git bisect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git status will work. If you are not on the latest commit (nor on any other branch), git status will show something like "HEAD detached at 4791138".

Your problem is that you are adding a "." after the hash. That is telling git to checkout all files at that commit, instead of moving HEAD to the old commit.

Try just doing `git checkout <sha1 hash>` (no ".")

Comment: No, git status does not say that the HEAD is detached. I dont have any modified files to stash/commit. When I checkout an old commit, all files after that commit show up as modified files.

Comment: Updated my answer, I realized the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question; removing the dot at the end of the checkout command

```
git checkout <SHA1 HASH> .
```

now tells me that the HEAD is detached.